# How do I end my program after you correctly guess the word?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating this game called "Fruit Guessing". I have a list of 9 fruits and I have the game working properly up until you guess all of the letters correct. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to get the game to end. I tried to get it to end on line 44 of the code I made a variable and everytime you guess a correct letter it adds 1 to that variable. The variable is called letters_guessed_correct. I tried to get it so that when letters_guessed_correct is equal to the length of the random fruit that was chosen it would say "congratulations! You guessed the fruit I was thinking of!" but I can't get that part to work and if I got it to work I'm still not sure how to get it to end the game. This is a project for school and it is due on Tuesday. It is my 15% of my grade in Computer Science Principles. Please help me.

I am running Python 3 on a website called repl.it

Here is the full code:

```
import random
def beginning_of_program():
    user_value = input('Would you like to look at the instructions?:')
    if user_value=='yes':
        instructions_page()
    elif user_value=='no':
        user_value=input('Are you ready to play Fruit Guessing?:')
        if user_value=='yes':
            run_game()
def instructions_page():
    print()
    print('1. I am going to come up with random fruits.')
    print()
    print('2. Try and guess the letters in the word')
    print()
    print('3. Write all of your guesses in lowercase letters')
    print()
    print('4. If you guess wrong 7 times then the game ends')
    print()
    user_value=input('Are you ready to play Fruit Guessing?:')
    if user_value=='no':
        print('Okay, have a good day')
    elif user_value=='yes':
        run_game()
def run_game():
    wordlist=['apple','orange','grape','kale','kiwi','mango','cherry','peach','plum']
    randfruit=random.choice(wordlist)
    blanks='_ '*len(randfruit)
    letters_guessed_correct=0
    print()
    print("Word: ",blanks)
    newblanks=blanks
    count=7
    while count>0:
        letters_guessed_correct=0
        letters_guessed_list=[]
        letters_guessed_correct_list=[]
        print()
        guess=input('Guess a letter from the fruit that I am thinking of:')
        if letters_guessed_correct==len(randfruit):
            print('Congratulations! You guessed the correct fruit I was thinking of!')
            exit()
        elif guess in letters_guessed_list:
            print('You have already guessed this letter, please guess again.')
        elif len(guess) !=1:
            print('Guess one letter at a time!')
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print('Please only guess letters')
        else:
            for letters in randfruit:
                if guess==letters:
                    if guess not in letters_guessed_list:
                        letterindex=randfruit.index(guess)
                        newblanks=newblanks[:letterindex*2]+guess+newblanks[letterindex*2+1:]
                        print(newblanks)
                        print('Guess is correct!')
                        letters_guessed_correct += 1
                        letters_guessed_correct_list.append(guess)
                        letters_guessed_list.append(guess)
                        break
            if guess not in randfruit:
                if count!=0:
                    count -= 1
                    letters_guessed_list.append(guess)
                    print("Guess is wrong!",count,"more failed attempts left.")
                    print()
                    print("Word:",newblanks)
                    print("Guess is wrong!",count,"more failed attempts left.")
                    print()
                    print("Word:",randfruit)
                    print()
                    print('You guessed,',str(letters_guessed_list))
                    print("Guess is wrong!",count,"more failed attempts left."
```

Comment: Posting code as images or external links just makes it harder for people to help you.  Post the code as text directly in your question.

Comment: Generally, you would have a `while True:` loop, and then `break` out of it when you want to end.

Comment: set `count=0` and it should exit `while` loop. You run code in function so you can use `return` to exit function

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def beginning_of_program():
    user_value = raw_input('Would you like to look at the instructions?:')
    if user_value.lower() == 'yes':
        instructions_page()
    elif user_value.lower() == 'no':
        user_value=raw_input('Are you ready to play Fruit Guessing?:')
        if user_value=='yes':
            run_game()
def instructions_page():
    print('I am going to come up with random fruits.')
    print('Try and guess the letters in the word')
    print('Write all of your guesses in lowercase letters')
    print('If you guess wrong 7 times then the game ends')
    user_value=raw_input('Are you ready to play Fruit Guessing?:')
    if user_value=='no':
        print('Okay, have a good day')
    elif user_value=='yes':
        run_game()
def run_game():
    wordlist=['apple','orange','grape','kale','kiwi','mango','cherry','peach','plum']
    randfruit=random.choice(wordlist)
    blanks='_ '*len(randfruit)
    letters_guessed_correct=0
    print()
    print("Word: ",blanks)
    newblanks=blanks
    count=7
    while count>0:
        letters_guessed_correct=0
        letters_guessed_list=[]
        letters_guessed_correct_list=[]
        print()
        guess=raw_input('Guess a letter from the fruit that I am thinking of:')
        if guess in letters_guessed_list:
            print('You have already guessed this letter, please guess again.')
        elif len(guess) !=1:
            print('Guess one letter at a time!')
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print('Please only guess letters')
        else:
            for letters in randfruit:
                if guess==letters:
                    if guess not in letters_guessed_list:
                        letterindex=randfruit.index(guess)
                        newblanks=newblanks[:letterindex*2]+guess+newblanks[letterindex*2+1:]
                        print(newblanks)
                        print('Guess is correct!')
                        letters_guessed_correct += 1
                        letters_guessed_correct_list.append(guess)
                        letters_guessed_list.append(guess)
                        break
            if guess not in randfruit:
                count -= 1
                letters_guessed_list.append(guess)
                print("Guess is wrong!",count,"more failed attempts left.")
                print()
                print("Word:",newblanks)

        if newblanks.replace(" ", "") == randfruit:
            print('Congratulations! You guessed the correct fruit I was thinking of!')
            exit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    beginning_of_program()
```